# Disable the Refreshed Selected Content Root Pop-up in IntelliJ gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

In IntelliJ it seems like whenever I save a file there is this annoying green pop-up notifier at the very bottom that obscures my bottom toolbar, i.e. where terminal, messages, debug usually are.

It's usually "Refreshed selected content roots" which I believe is a gradle thing. There is no obvious way to dismiss it and it just trips me up every time.

As I often make a change and then want to switch to SonarLint or Terminal or whatever and it's blocking the button.

I know obvious workarounds like moving buttons around, but I kind of don't understand what that notifier is even called to configure it or even google it.

[image]

Comment: What third-party plug-ins do you have installed? It doesn't seem to be a message from IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CrazyCoder would know what he's talking about, I found that the alert is caused by the (hasn't been updated in years with no configurable settings) **AccuRev** Plugin.

You can search this PDF for "Selected Content Roots" and you'll find it:
https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/AccuRev/Plugins/IntelliJ/2014.2/intellij-2014.2-users_guide-en.pdf

This means if I don't plan on moving files around I can logout or disable the plugin then run `accurev stat -mO` when I'm done. There have been plenty of other reasons to do that, so this just added to the heap.